# Reading rows from PHPspreadsheet and in which format its stored when working with json & array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am reading rows, customer information, from an excel spreadsheet using PHPSpreadsheet, looping through each row and doing multiple post requests to an endpoint

**1st request:**

```
/**
 * Load, read and store xlsx file as array
 */
$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileName = 'testData.xlsx';

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Advise the Reader that we only want to load cell data  **/
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

//convert to array
$sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, false, false, true); 

//loop through each row in the spreadsheet
foreach($sheetData as $cellData){

$curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'testendpointurl.com',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
      "full_name": "'.$cellData['A'].'",
      "price": "'.$cellData['B'].'"
  }',
  ));
}
```

The endpoint specifies it needs full_name as string but price as integer, instead of wrapping $cellData['B'] in double quotes, should I omit the quotes to pass as integer? Is this way of adding the variable to the json body correct? Both seem to work and is accepted by the endpoint but want to have it correct to prevent any issues in the future

**2nd request:**

I need to post form data

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'testendpointurl.com',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('full_name' => $cellData['A'],'account_number' => $cellData['C']),
    ));
```

Again full_name needs to be sent as a string as well as an account number. Are these array key values actually sent as string to the endpoint and exists as a string? Is $cellData['A'] = 'string' at all times? Or what happens with the account_number which is always an integer? is this then stored and sent as $cellData['A'] = 100578 or $cellData['A'] = "100578" ?

Comment: _"should I omit the quotes to pass as integer?"_ - you should not assemble JSON "manually" in the first place. Populate the according data structure, and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: _"Are these array key values actually sent as string to the endpoint and exists as a string?"_ - HTTP does know any "data types" for application/x-www-form-urlencoded parameters, _all_ the values are text values.

Comment: @CBroe why should I not assemble JSON manually? I sometimes work with deeply nested JSON so to replicate this to array and then encode is tedious. If I wanted to speed up this process I could simply json_decode the initial JSON to array, copy that output and then encode it again but why do that? Its all the same thing?

Comment: Because its error-prone. The probability that you introduce syntax errors that invalidate your JSON, is just much higher. For example if either of the two $cellData values you are using there could ever contain a `"` or an unescaped line break, this would break.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for pointing that out and yes makes total sense but the input for $cellData is cleaned up before its processed and this project is a stop gap solution anyway. Removing those double quotes in the JSON to pass as integer is technically correct right, "price": '.$cellData['B'].' ?

Comment: Yes, without the quotes, it will be interpreted as a numeric value.